# Question invalidly closed as "seeking recommendation" by moderator

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

This question:

[How can I translate this IDNA URL to Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67701899/idna-tounicode-for-full-url)

Was closed and I don't see why. It's certainly an answerable question. The user simply needs to parse the URL first:

```go
package main

import (
   "golang.org/x/net/idna"
   "net/url"
)

func main() {
   p, e := url.Parse("https://xn---36-mddtcafmzdgfgpbxs0h7c.xn--p1ai")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   u, e := idna.ToUnicode(p.Host)
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   println(u == "природный-источник36.рф")
}
```

but a moderator closed as "recommending a tool". That's not what is happening here. The user just wants a solution. They gave the problem an earnest try, and posted what they tried, and they just want to know what they did wrong, or if their approach is just totally off. Please reopen this valid question.

Comment: Is there some option **or another GO package** (cite from question). Not saying whether the question should be closed or not, but things like this can trigger close voters.

Comment: @BDL It's trivial to edit that phrase out to make it on-topic.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't edit the phrase out. It's saying that the OP is open to solutions using other packages too, which is fine. Asking only for another package is not.

Comment: @TylerH: It is, and I already started to edit, but you were faster.

Comment: @ErikA I'm on the fence there; asking for a package recommendation is off-topic IMO whether it's the whole question or a part of it.

Comment: @BDL Sorry, I pulled a FGITW on you it seems

Answer (score 2):

I removed the "or another Go package" fragment (among other edits), which makes the question on-topic, and I cast a vote to reopen the question. It is now open.

Comment: And I voted to close as "no longer reproducible."  Nothing more to see here.